# In React component, in useEffect, clearing timer leads to unwelcome results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React App I have input which should fire its content to Redux Store but with random delay (between 5 and 10s). As it is with delay and with random, it was clear for me that the logic should be in useEffect. So I came to the code as follows:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState<Message>({} as Message); 


    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(message, "message");
            !isEmpty(message) && addMessage(message);
        }, randomInteger(5, 10) * 1000);
        // return () => clearTimeout(timer);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [message]);
```

message here is the actual message to be sent and comes from input to state. The above useEffect code works perfectly when there is no return function clearing timeout.When the return function exists, the effect is as follows: when I type messages quickly one after another part of them is not sent; sent is always the last one. OK, I can not forget about returning timer clearing function but as far as I understand I should use it to be inline with rules and limit risk of memory leakage. How to solve it?

Comment: When you type quickly and you set the message at random between 5 and 10 seconds it can happen that not the last message will be saved in the store. What is the reason to do that?

Comment: Messages are set to store onclik what makes it immediately. It is the issue of the effect code, the answer below is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to add timeouts to an array and clear them during unmounting.

```
const timeouts = []

useEffect(() => {
    timeouts.push(
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(message, "message");
            !isEmpty(message) && addMessage(message);
        }, randomInteger(5, 10) * 1000);
    )
}, [message]);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => timeouts.forEach(t => clearTimeout(t));
}, [])
```